# Motions with tweens one after another in Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript

I have some problems with motions and tweens:
I want move my sprite to to the bottom right corner (800,600) then to the top left corner (0,0). But my tweens arent waiting each other.

```
motion.toBotCorner(currentSprite);
motion.toTopCorner(currentSprite);
```

And this is in my Motion class:

```
        public function toBotCorner(currSpr:Sprite):void {
            TweenLite.to(currSpr, 3, {x:800, y:600});
        }
        public function toTopCorner(currSpr:Sprite):void {
            TweenLite.to(currSpr, 3, {x:0, y:0});
        }
```

How to make the first one proccess and then the second? Thank you!

Comment: You can create sequences of tweens with TimelineLite, it is probably the easiest way: https://greensock.com/getting-started-as#timeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the **'onComplete'** provided by TweenLite on your first animation. It requires a method name, and use the **'onCompleteParams'** to send the parameters to the method call.

So, your code would look like this now:

```
   public function toBotCorner(currSpr:Sprite):void {
        TweenLite.to(currSpr, 3, {x:800, y:600, onComplete:toTopCorner, onCompleteParams:[currSpr]});
   }
   public function toTopCorner(currSpr:Sprite):void {
        TweenLite.to(currSpr, 3, {x:0, y:0});
   }
```

Note that the onCompleteParams: is an array as a method could have multiple parameters to be passed.

Here's what the docs says:

**onComplete : Function** - A function that should be called when the tween has completed

**onCompleteParams : Array** - An Array of parameters to pass the onComplete function.